# location.href not working on any browser

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript code
I want to click on a button and redirect to another page after checking a password 
here is my code ;

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var admin = document.getElementById('admin');
      admin.addEventListener('click',f_admin);
      function f_admin(e){
        //event.preventDefault();
        var conf=prompt('Saisisser le mot de passe Administrateur');
        if(conf=='1')   window.location.href ='http://mywebsite.com/includes/index.php';                            
        else alert("Mot de passe incorrecte");
        return false;
       }

   </script>
   <script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

thanks

Comment: try `window.location` only

Comment: If the first `<script>` is in `<head>`, enclose the whole code in the first `<script>` between `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {` and `});`.

Comment: Are you getting the prompt?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? If so, why didn't you fix those problems before coming here?

Comment: @anqooqie If that's the problem he would be getting errors saying that `null` has no method `addEventListener`.

Comment: tried window.location only didn t work

Comment: yes i m getting the value of prompt

Comment: your code is running before any elements are present on the page. SHow a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: i tried this code

Comment: sorry will send proper code

Comment: You should use `document.location` to redirect to another page.

Comment: i just add the document.addEventListener("DOMCententLoaded ",function(){ and}); thanks anqooqie